# Who developed the overall plan for the attack on the Second Death Star? Was it Admiral Ackbar?

Tags: star-wars

The plan of attack on a Second Death Star, in general, was:

- The fleet initiates major action, drawing attention of the Imperials
- A commando team - slipping in all the hubbub under Imperial noses with older codes - lands on Endor's moon and disables the shield generators projecting the shield around Death Star
- A rebel force attacks Imperials near Sullust to lure the Imperial fleet protecting Death Star elsewhere
- The rebel fleet's small craft attack and destroy the (supposedly defenseless as per the prior bullet point) Death Star (which had supposedly NOT had operational defenses), by detonating armaments in its internals.

**Is there any canon confirmation that the overall strategy was developed by Admiral Ackbar?** (as opposed to others developing it or participating equally with Ackbar)?

Comment: the "overall strategy" is wrong within this form, 1 : the commando teem was supposed to disables the shield generators *before* the rebel force attacks the death star. 2 : "The Imperial fleet protecting Death Star" was not supposed to be there, they where hiding (remember : "It's a trap!")

Comment: I seem to recall Lando and Leia discussing the planning of the battle on Kessel as though they were actively involved in one of the recent books.  As well as Han saying it was Leia's plan to infiltrate Endor in RotJ.  I will see if i can find it and make an answer.

Comment: In an unused scene, it would have been shown that the overall plan was actually concocted by the protocol droid C-3PO... but he thought it was doomed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ackbar), just prior to the Battle of Endor:

> Mon Mothma, noticing the skills of Ackbar, named him Supreme Commander of the Rebel Fleet and head of all Rebellion military operations.

So, he would be analogous to Eisenhower in his role as Supreme Allied Commander Europe.

While he might not have been the only planner involved in the Battle of Endor, he would have had final say on what the plan would be and whether it would go forward. He also appears to have complete command in the battle itself - although, he does agree to Lando's suggestion that they close into the Imperial Fleet while waiting for the shield around the Death Star to be taken down.

Comment: This is a good answer, Ackbar was in overall command of the Alliance Military, but Crix Madine was also a  key part of playing the commando raid on the moon (enough so that he was called on to Brief everyone about the particulars of that portion of the plan). It's implied elsewhere in the Legends universe that Ackbar was always a strategic thinker, primarily based on fleet maneuvering, and had little to do with 'land' battles.